# edit text field validation in android from web service

Tags: java, android, web-services, validation, android-edittext

i have developed one android app.

The app is performs the value is inserting from android to mysql database.

Here i have called Soap web service.

Here how can i validate my edittext field.

this is my webservice code:

```
public class RetailerWs {

public String insertData(String Firstname,String Lastname){

 try{

 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xcart-432pro","root","");
 PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO xcart_customers(firstname,lastname) VALUES ('"+Firstname+"','"+Lastname+"');");
 int result = statement.executeUpdate();
  }

 catch(Exception exc){
 System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
  }

return "Registration is  successfull!!";
}

 }
```

This is my android code:

```
   btninsert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    btninsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
         insertValues();
        }
    });
}
 public void insertValues(){
 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
 EditText Firstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_userName);
 String user_Name = Firstname.getText().toString();
 EditText Lastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_password);
 String user_Password = Lastname.getText().toString();
 PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
    unameProp.setName("Firstname");//Define the variable name in the web service method
    unameProp.setValue(user_Name);//Define value for fname variable
    unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
    request.addProperty(unameProp);//Pass properties to the variable

  //Pass value for userPassword variable of the web service
    PropertyInfo passwordProp =new PropertyInfo();
    passwordProp.setName("Lastname");
    passwordProp.setValue(user_Password);
    passwordProp.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(passwordProp);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try{
     androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();


        TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        result.setText(response.toString());

       }
     catch(Exception e){

      }
```

How can i validate the edittext field.please help me

Comment: what type of validation you required? Do you want to check for empty fields?

Comment: yes i have  to check empty field validation for both firstname and lastname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can validate your strings if they are empty or not by doing the following:
1- first Declare your EditText fields in your class not in your method:

```
EditText Firstname;
EditText Lastname;
```

2- then initialize those variables in your onCreate() method:

```
Firstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_userName);
Lastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_password);
```

3- before calling the insertValues(); method do the following:

```
if(Firstname.equals(null)||Lastname.equals(null))
{Toast.makeText(context, "Enter Firstname and/or LastName", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
else
{insertValues();}
```

hope this help you

Comment: i have used below code.it is worked well:EditText Firstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_userName);
             EditText Lastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_password);
                if(Firstname.getText().length()==0)
             {
              Firstname.setError("please enter the firstname");
             }
             else if(Lastname.getText().length()==0)
              {
               Lastname.setError("please enter the lastname");
             }
             else
             { 
              insertValues();
             }

Comment: :Hi i have to removed my EditText declaration in insertValues(); means doesn't insert the values in my database at the same time my app is force closed.after that i have to declare the Edittext declaration is my onCreate and insertValues() function means am getting the correct o/p.please remove that line from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use below condition in this android code:

```
            EditText Firstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_userName);
            EditText Lastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_password);
            if(Firstname.getText().length()==0)
            {
                Firstname.setError("please enter the firstname");
            }
            else if(Lastname.getText().length()==0)
                {
                    Lastname.setError("please enter the lastname");
            }
            else
            {   
                insertValues();
            }
```

it is successfully worked for me